# Spark History Server 403 Access

Tags: apache-spark, datastax-enterprise

I'm able to navigate the Spark History pages, but when I click on any of the **stdout** or **stderr** links to view the executor logs, I get the error page:

HTTP ERROR 403 
Problem accessing /api/v1/applications/app-20190117003054-0004/executors. Reason:

You are not allowed to access this resource. Any idea why?

My spark-defaults.conf has these logging configs:

`spark.eventLog.dir dsefs:///spark/events
spark.eventLog.enabled true
spark.history.fs.logDirectory dsefs:///spark/events`

Comment: please provide more information - what you're using (version of DSE), what authentication schemas are configured, etc.

Comment: Where are you storing events of spark history and logs? Are them on some nfs/s3 /hdfs or just in local folders?

Comment: @SergeHarnyk I've updated the post with the history and logs configs.